# How do I disable a button in my angular controller if a condition is met?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, frontend

I need to disable a button if a boolean variable (returned from back-end) is true.

This is my incomplete function on my angular controller, how do I change my controller and HTML button to make this work?

```
$scope.flagInLavorazione = function (flagInLavorazione) {
    if (flagInLavorazione === true){
        // What to add here?
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You're looking for [`ng-disabled`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngDisabled). Simply assign it a property from your controller. When it's `true`, the element will be disabled. Populate that property with the value from the back end.

Comment: Could you provide a code example? I've tried something, but couldn't make it work.

Answer (score 2):

For AngularJS, you can use:

```
<button ng-disabled="isNotReady">I'm a button</button>
```

Comment: Are you sure you haven't mixed the syntax of `AngularJS` and `Angular 2+`?

Comment: oh, you are right. Original question was about AngularJS, not A2+. Well, all we need: `<button ng-disabled="$scope.isNotReady">I'm a button</button>`

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** According to your requirements, you would use:

```
$scope.disabilitaConvalida = function (flagInLavorazione) { 
    $scope.saldoNegativo = false; 
    if (flagInLavorazione === false) { 
        $scope.saldoNegativo = true;
    } 
}
```

And in your template:

```
<button ng-disabled="saldoNegativo"></button>
```

---

Original Answer:

You set in your template:

```
<button ng-disabled="condition"></button>
```

And

`$scope.condition = true` or `false` in your controller based on the backend variable.

Comment: `$scope.disabilitaConvalida = function (flagInLavorazione) {
        var saldoNegativo = false;
        if (flagInLavorazione === false) {
            saldoNegativo = true;
           
        }
        return saldoNegativo;
        




    };`

This is my function on the controller, and i call the button with `ng-disabled="$scope.disabilitaConvalida(data.flagInLavorazione)"` 
Unfortunately it still doesn't work, what am i doing wrong?

Comment: Edited my answer, please see

Comment: Unfortunately it still doesn't work, as this doesn't pass my backend boolean without some data.flagInLavorazione on the button. How can i adapt this to get the actual variable from backend?

Comment: Wherever you are getting the data, you just call `$scope.disabilitaConvalida(data.flagInLavorizione)`, and if your `button` has `ng-disabled="saldoNegativo"`, it will work.

Comment: I don't understand how to call it outside of the button. Could you provide an example?

Comment: Add the code where your variable is being returned from backend, in your question.